# Windows 8 User Control Navigation issue

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

My requirement is that I have to add one common `usercontrol` in all my pages. The `usercontrol` will have 5 buttons. When user presses on one button navigation should happen to that button related page. I'm handling same thing in windows phone with following code:

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(
                        new Uri(PageUrls.INCOMEEXPENCE_PAGE, UriKind.Relative));
```

Now I want this in my window 8 application. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It will be like this

```
private void btnMyPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage),YOUR_PARAMETER);
}
```

Where `MyPage` is XAML page and `YOUR_PARAMETER` is object parameter if you want to pass some data while navigating, it's optional. You can access that parameter in `OnNavigatedTo` event with `e.Parameter`.

Please check this article for more info : [WinRT XAML Navigating from Page to Page: How it differs from Windows Phone 7](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-navigating-from-page-to-page-how-it-differs-from-windows-phone-7/)

**EDIT 1 :**

As per your comment, you want master page like feature in you app. So I would suggest you to check this : [Windows 8 XAML Tips - Master Pages](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2013/windows-8-xaml-tips-master-pages).

Moreover, I recommend you to check [Windows Store Apps samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/). It has also UI like you want, it has header & footer and the various scenarios are displayed in center.

Comment: Thanks For Reply,

But my question is navigation in user control.i was unable to findout Frame.navigate() method in User control. that methos is working only in XAML Page.

Comment: I think navigation in user control is not possible. So I suggest you to create page instead of user control.

Comment: i did it in windows phone.in windows 8 they made small changes. actually i want to add that user control as footer of all my pages. so in that synario i can't add XAML page ryt?.

Comment: Thanks for upvote Rajesh, I also request you to accept it as answer. You will find "check" mark below upvote button, just click on it.